# Adding custom code into generated entity classes

Tags: android, greendao

I am using [google-http-java-client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/) to simplify my communication with web and automate parsing server's responses. So I need to annotate members of my POJO classes by annotattion @Key(name) like in [this example](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/dailymotion-simple-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/dailymotion/cmdline/simple/DailyMotionSample.java?repo=samples):

```
public static class Video {

   @Key
   public String id;

   @Key
   public String title;

   @Key
   public String url;
}
```

After I receive server's response I want to save these entities into database. So I have to generate this class by GreenDAO. And main question is how I can insert anotations @Key into generated class?
Yes, I know I can insert some code into generated class. This [topic](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/modelling-entities/) describes this ability. But as I understand I can insert only custom members, methods and includes.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at [Path's fork](https://github.com/path/greenDAO) and use at your own risk. it has support for adding annotations.

Comment: I just sent a [pull request](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/pull/67) that includes related code for adding annotation support. Not sure when (if) it will make it to master repo but you can use it as a patch if you prefer to stick with main project.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not currently supported by greenDAO. For future reference, I opened a ticket:
https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/66

There are ways to work around this, but you must be cautious. You can stop generating certain entities using `yourEntity.setSkipGeneration(true)`. If you decide to go this road you must always supply a constructor like the generated code does. Keep this in mind if properties change.

Comment: so how to stop generating entities's DAOs by "Build" process in the greenDao 3, I just want to generate the DAOs once then stop re-generating them on every 'Build' process